# Pyqt5 Qtextedit settext delay

Tags: python, pyqt5, qtextedit

I will create a text editor program that uses fonts. However, it takes a considerable amount of time to open a 5MB text file.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QTextEdit, QAction, QFileDialog
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon


class MyApp(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.textEdit = QTextEdit()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.textEdit)
        self.statusBar()

        openFile = QAction(QIcon('open.png'), 'Open', self)
        openFile.setShortcut('Ctrl+O')
        openFile.setStatusTip('Open New File')
        openFile.triggered.connect(self.showDialog)

        menubar = self.menuBar()
        menubar.setNativeMenuBar(False)
        fileMenu = menubar.addMenu('&File')
        fileMenu.addAction(openFile)

        self.setWindowTitle('File Dialog')
        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 300, 200)
        self.show()

    def showDialog(self):
        fname = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, 'Open file', './')

        if fname[0]:
            f = open(fname[0], 'r', encoding='utf-8')

            with f:
                data = f.read()
                self.textEdit.setText(data)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = MyApp()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

So is there a way to reduce the time it takes to open the file?

Comment: 5Mb text file is huge, it's "A Game of Thrones" three times.

Comment: If you want to work with such files you have to reimplement `QTextEdit` text rendering and line wrapping.

Comment: You could try QPlainTextEdit. It has only limited support for html via the underlying QTextDocument but it's much more responsive than QTextEdit.